# Integrating the FB SDK in Android project

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have a working android project.
I'm trying to integrate the Facebook SDK for android.
As I see in the installation instructions.. I need to unzip the package.Then import the facebook folder as a project.
Then in my project in properties ads a new library  and choose the facebooksdk project.
When I do this I'm getting error

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Which is for the android-support-v4.jar file.
I have once the that file in my project libs folder and again in the facebookSDK project.
If I make them the same files (copy one over the other) I'm getting errors in the FacebookSDK project...

I'm really confused,can you please help to work this out =]

Edit:
I did change the android support jar file on both places with v13.
Now I'm receiving errors again in the FBSDK project.
[image: errors]

Comment: You need to make the version of v4 jar same in both.

Comment: If I make them the same files (copy one over the other) I'm getting errors in the FacebookSDK project...

Comment: Update android support library from Android SDK Manager. Currently I have android-support-v13.jar file in project library and android-support-v4.jar file in Facebook SDK project and I am not getting Jar mismatch errors. I hope this helps

Comment: You don't need to change android support library on both places. Just change it in your project. I have mentioned that in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Downloaded the eclipse package again.Installed all things in Android Manager.
Removed the android support v4 from the FB SDK project.
Now it's showing me errors in the FB project,but I can export my application without a problem.
The FB Dashboard shows its working ;)